# in batch For loop , echo %%i:~0,5% doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe, script, shell-script

Why doesn't this command work? How can I correct it?

```
for /F %%i in ('dir c:\logs /A:-D/B') do @echo %%i:~0,5%
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Why doesn't this command work?

> for /F %%i in ('dir c:\logs /A:-D/B') do @echo %%i:~0,5%

You need to use a temporary variable as you cannot extract text from a loop variable.

You need to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Try the following cmd file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%i in ('dir c:\logs /A:-D/B') do (
   set _temp=%%i
   set _result=!_temp:~0,5!
   echo !_result!
   )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Endlocal - Local environment variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [Setlocal - Local variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)